# How to invite someone to The Hangar

Tags: discussion, chat

After so many years, I **just** figured this out and thought to share it.

It was never clear to me why chat sometimes would show me the option to invite someone to The Hangar, to say discuss something related to a post, and sometimes it doesn't:

> [image]

versus

> [image]

It turns out, I have to be *in The Hangar,* for the option to appear.

The other person you're inviting does not need to have used chat recently as I once thought!